# Convergence of Discretized Geodesics?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemmanian manifold, $p\in M$ and $V\in T_p(M)$.

Suppose $f^{-1}:U_p \mapsto \mathbb{R}^D$ is a diffeomorphism of a neighborhood of p to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and define the sequence:
\begin{equation}
\{p_i := f(G_{f^{-1}[p_{i-1}]}^{-1}(V)+ f^{-1}[p_{i-1}])  \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}},
\end{equation}
where $p_0=p$ and $G_{f^{-1}[p_{i-1}]}^{-1}$ is the inverse of the pull-back of the metric tensor at $f(p)$ to $p$ in $U$.

Then it seems *intuitive* to me that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{f(p_i)\}$ converges to the image of geodesic in $M$ with velocity $V$, but how can I prove this?

I was thinking of taking a discrete derivatives but still this is not obvious to me.  Thank you.

Comment: There appear to be typos, enough that I'm having trouble sussing out what the intuition here is supposed to be. For instance, $p$ begins as a point in the manifold but is later added to something that looks like a tangent vector (which seems to make sense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but perhaps not in $M$); also, $G^{-1}_q$ depends on a thing $q$ which hasn't been defined, and my attempts to fix whatever typos are here run me into the problem of not having a coherent way to apply $G^{-1}_{p_{i-1}}$ to $V$. Perhaps it might help to either carefully fix the typos or to describe the intuitive picture?

Comment: Fixed the typos, sorry I types this up in the middle of the night.

Comment: It is still not clear, the tangent space in $p$ and $p'$ is different, in order to "add vectors" from different tangent spaces you need to use a connection.
In particular, why this inductive process stays in $U_{p}$?
Moreover, the metric tensor is a bilinear form on the tangent space, where is the second vector?

Comment: Its the local matrix representation.